# Can't bind to 'errorStateMatcher' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular-material, karma-jasmine, angular7

I get an error while running npm test

```
Can't bind to 'errorStateMatcher' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("dth">
        <input matInput placeholder="Product Name" formControlName="prod_name"
               [ERROR ->][errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
```

**My Spec file is as follows**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProductAddComponent } from './product-add.component';
import { FormControl, FormGroupDirective, FormBuilder, FormGroup, NgForm, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

describe('ProductAddComponent', () => {
  let component: ProductAddComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductAddComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
      declarations: [ ProductAddComponent ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductAddComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

How do I provide `errorStateMatcher` to test unit?

Comment: You probably need to import the material design input module (`MatInputModule`) into your test bed since that property goes with that. If you want to skip these type of errors like you are doing with the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`, I think you can use the `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` schema as well.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel thanks, this removed the error

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you need to import MatInputModule.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add `matInput` attribute to the `input` element.

Answer (score 0):

If You are getting this error while testing make sure you mock `matInput` aswell. That was my Issue. I imported `MatInputModule` in spec file, but that caused more errors later.